# How to build a TypeScript module that is importing from another local module in monorepo?

Tags: typescript, monorepo, tsc

In my project I have created a module for some common express things that I need to use in several microservices in my monorepo. The structure of the repository is following

```
myProject/
|
|-services/
| |-service1/
|   |-src/
|   | |-fileImportingFromShared.ts
|   |-tsconfig.js
|
|-shared-modules/
| |-express/
|   |-src/
|   | |-someFiles.ts
|   |-tsconfig.js
|
|-tsconfig.js // root level tsconfig, which other configs are extending
```

During development I have no problems importing and using files from the shared module. The problems arise when I try to build any of the services with `tsc` I get following errors, which are weird, becuase some of those errors come even from inside comments in files in node modules.

```js
../../shared-modules/express/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts:1199:16 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1199      * A node `http.Server` is returned, with this
                    ~~~~

../../shared-modules/express/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts:1200:33 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1200      * application (which is a `Function`) as its
                                     ~~~~~~~~

../../shared-modules/express/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts:1268:1 - error TS1160: Unterminated template literal.

1268
```

In my root level tsconfig I have set `skipLibCheck: true`. I have also tried to exclude node modules with several recursive glob patterns in the root config and even in the other tsconfigs, but nothing seems to work. What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer. In order to do this, one must use `yarn`.

I configured my project to use `yarn3` and its workspaces and now everything works perfectly exactly as it should